# Struts2 jackson throws exception for hibernate pojo

Tags: json, hibernate, struts2, jackson

I am getting following exception on struts2 json...any ideas?

I am using Hibernate: 3.6.1, and struts2 with json plugin.

Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.model.Task.getHibernateLazyInitializer()

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain... Hibernate/JPA decorates the entities so that they can do their magic.  Long story short you need to prune the entity before returning it as json using exclude properties.

Easiest way is to examine the object at run time, you'll find the offending property then create an exclude regex to prevent the json plugin from serialization.

As a sanity test you can prove there is a bad property by simply defining include properties for the properties you know to exist, which will produce the object you need although it makes what should be an automatic process a pretty manual one, where fining the right exclude property aught to be the same between all hibernate entities.

For examples of include and exclude parameters see: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html